# Select & onChange | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

In my view, I have this form with the select function:

```
<form id="form_id">
<%= form.select('id','name',  @document.informations.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.name] },
        options={},{:onChange => 'submit()'}) -%>
</form>
```

How can I use the selected name in the rest of my view ?

I saw this in other topics:

```
$('#id_name').val();
```

But it didn't work for me, it says:

```
`$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that particular error because the `$('#id_name').val()` is JavaScript, not Ruby, but you've put it within erb tags.

When you visit a page `/documents/3` in your browser, Rails will run the code in your controller, and send back some HTML to your browser. That HTML can load CSS and JavaScript, but that's run after your Ruby program has finished - and may not be run at all, depending on the browser. How you use the name of the selected item in your view depends on what you're doing with it.

If you're storing it in the database somewhere, then you should start by getting this working just in Ruby. For instance, if your `@document` has a `selected_informations` attribute, you could use that in the rest of your page, and pass it to your `form.select` to pre-select it in the page. [The Rails Guides documentation has more info on this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease).

If you're not storing it in the database, then you can get the value of your box out with JavaScript whenever it changes. Here's some sample code that prints out the name of the selected item to the JavaScript console whenever a `<select>` box gets changed. I've included it in `<script>` tags so you can drop it straight into your view for testing, but you should put it into a dedicated JavaScript file if you adapt it for your project.

```
<script>
$('select').on('change', function(ev) { 
    var selected_item = $(ev.currentTarget).val();
    console.log("Your select value is " + selected_item);
});
</script>
```

One final thing to note is that your existing `form.select` tag is set up to call a method `submit()` whenever its value gets changed. `submit` is just a name, so that function *could* do anything... but I'd guess it's submitting the form whenever an item is selected. This sends a request to your Rails server and refreshes the page, so beware - if you're using an event listener on `change` to update the current page, you won't see those changes on the new, refreshed page (and should use a server-side solution instead).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However the sample code doesn't work for me. It doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: The sample code won't change your page; it will print things to the JavaScript console, so you can see an example of getting the value. Here's instructions for [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console).

Comment: Great I've got it ! But there isn't any easy way to print the selected value directly in my view ?

Comment: In your Rails view? No. Ruby runs your code and sends the HTML down to the browser, then it's done. At that point the user hasn't selected anything; there's nothing to print in your view.

If your Rails app is storing the selected item then you can render it in the view directly. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to update the page in the browser, or do a form submission back to your Rails app that renders a new page.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try the form submission solution.